# Data label Properties not being set for a chart in PPT

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to set the data-label properties of a data point using this code snippet, but for some reason the properties are not being set as intended. [ Please see the pic for better clarity ].

A workaround could be using the `Reset label Text` [ See Pic - 2 ] thus forcing the data-label to update the set properties. But I couldn't find the vba equivalent of the same. Help.

```
 'This is happening inside a loop

 Dim thisbarpoint As Point
 Set thisbarpoint = thischart.FullSeriesCollection(ibar).Points(jbar)

 thisbarpoint.DataLabel.ShowCategoryName = True
 thisbarpoint.DataLabel.ShowValue = False
 thisbarpoint.DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = False

 Debug.Print thisbarpoint.DataLabel.caption
 Dim DataLabelCaption As String
 DataLabelCaption = thisbarpoint.DataLabel.caption
 Debug.Print DataLabelCaption 'This gives the value as 26.7%
```

**PIC-1:**

[image]

**PIC-2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```vb
Dim cht As Chart, s As Series
    
Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart
Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

Debug.Print s.HasDataLabels 'False

s.HasDataLabels = True
With s.DataLabels
    .ShowCategoryName = True
    .ShowValue = False
    .ShowSeriesName = False
End With
```

We can't know if your file is corrupted, or if the problem is elsewhere in code you didn't include.

Comment: This problem is only happening with a specific data point. It is a clustered column chart. For other data points, the code is working fine. I am trying to find the root cause because otherwise, this will bring down the confidence in macro.

Comment: OK - maybe add more code then, or share a copy of the slide with the chart?  There's nothing wrong with your posted code as far as I can see.

Comment: Finally, I made a new chart and copied the backend data to this one and now the code is working. Still the cause remains a mystery. The chart is definitely going in the paranormal deck...lol

Comment: Is there a way to use the `Reset Label Text` option in code. May be forcing it to refresh will work. I can't find the vba equivalent of the same though.

Comment: In Excel VBA that appears to be `.AutoText = True`  but I think that only clears and "manual" edits from the labels.